# How to identify package (re)defining \Eta At (or After) BeginDocument?

Tags: atbegindocument

If I were to construct an MWE, I would have my answer, but I am trying to avoid all of that trial and error.

So I am using XeLaTeX and loading lots and lots of packages directly and indirectly.

If I have something like

```
% [loads of stuff above this point]

% \newcommand{\Eta}{H} % Latin H causes fewer problems than using Greek.
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\Eta}{H} % Latin H causes fewer problems than using Greek.
\show\Eta
```

then I get that \Eta is defined to be Latin H.

But if I do

```
% [loads of stuff above this point]

\newcommand{\Eta}{H} % Latin H causes fewer problems than using Greek.
\begin{document}
% \renewcommand{\Eta}{H} % Latin H causes fewer problems than using Greek.
\show\Eta
```

Then `\show\Eta` tells me that

```
> \Eta=macro:
->\mitEta .
l.62 \show\Eta
```

and in some of the places in which I use `\Eta` in my document, I run into problems when the Greek letter is not in the fonts. For example, I get warnings like

```
Missing character: There is no  (U+1D6E8) in font Fira Sans Light/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
```

### I could remove packages to find the culprit

I do understand that I could identify the culprit by constructing various attempts at minimal working examples just using one package at a time. But I am hoping that there is a better way do approach this, as I have a lot of things that are loaded indirectly.

### I know I could work around this

I realize that I could work around this by any of

1. Using a control sequence other than `Eta`.
2. Just using "`H`" instead of "`\Eta`" in the body of what I have.
3. Wrapping my definition of `\Eta` in an `\AtBeginDocument` (or `\AfterBeginDocument`.

So I don't need an answer to get my stuff to work. But I am still curious about who might be defining `\Eta` at (or after) beginDocument.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which packages are leaving code in the begin document hook you can use `\ShowHook`

```
\documentclass{article}

% lots of excellent packages
\usepackage{longtable,dcolumn,colortbl,plain,bm,indentfirst,afterpage}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\ShowHook{begindocument}

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

Produces a log of

```
-> The hook 'begindocument':
> Code chunks:
>     color -> \def \KV@Gin@bbllx {\PackageError {luatex.def}{Options `bblly', 
`bblly', `bburx', `bbury',\MessageBreak `natheight' and `natwidth' are not\Mess
ageBreak supported by luatex driver:\MessageBreak use `viewport' instead}\@ehc 
}\let \KV@Gin@bblly \KV@Gin@bbllx \let \KV@Gin@bburx \KV@Gin@bbllx \let \KV@Gin
@bbury \KV@Gin@bbllx \let \KV@Gin@natwidth \KV@Gin@bbllx \let \KV@Gin@natheight
 \KV@Gin@bbllx \def \KV@Gin@bb {\PackageInfo {luatex.def}{Option `bb' equivalen
t to `viewport' with the luatex driver}\KV@Gin@viewport }\let \Gin@iii \Gin@iii
@vp \ifnum \mag =\@m \@ifundefined {stockwidth}{\@ifundefined {paperwidth}{}{\i
fdim \paperwidth >0pt\relax \ifdim \paperheight >0pt\relax \pagewidth =\paperwi
dth \pageheight =\paperheight \fi \fi }}{\ifdim \stockwidth >0pt\relax \ifdim \
stockheight >0pt\relax \setlength {\pagewidth }{\stockwidth }\setlength {\pageh
eight }{\stockheight }\else \ifdim \paperwidth >0pt\relax \ifdim \paperheight >
0pt\relax \setlength {\pagewidth }{\paperwidth }\setlength {\pageheight }{\pape
rheight }\fi \fi \fi \else \ifdim \stockwidth =0pt\relax \ifdim \paperwidth >0p
t\relax \ifdim \paperheight >0pt\relax \setlength {\pagewidth }{\paperwidth }\s
etlength {\pageheight }{\paperheight }\fi \fi \fi \fi }\fi \GPT@LoadSuppPdf \le
t \default@color \current@color \ifx \includegraphics \@undefined \else \@ifpac
kageloaded {pst-pdf}{}{\@ifpackageloaded {pdftricks}{}{\@ifpackageloaded {graph
ics}{\ifnum \directlua {tex.sprint(status.shell_escape)}>0 \edef \Gin@extension
s {\Gin@extensions ,.eps}\RequirePackage {epstopdf-base}[2009/07/12]\fi }{} }}\
fi 
>     colortbl -> \expandafter \def \expandafter \@tabarray \expandafter {\expa
ndafter \CT@start \@tabarray }\def \@tempa {$\hfil \egroup \box \z@ \box \tw@ }
\ifx \@tempa \DC@endright \def \DC@endright {$\hfil \egroup \ifx \DC@rl \bgroup
 \hskip \stretch {-.5}\box \z@ \box \tw@ \hskip \stretch {-.5}\else \box \z@ \b
ox \tw@ \fi }\else \def \@tempa {$\hfil \egroup \hfill \box \z@ \box \tw@ }\ifx
 \@tempa \DC@endright \def \DC@endright {$\hfil \egroup \hskip \stretch {.5}\bo
x \z@ \box \tw@ \hskip \stretch {-.5}}\fi \fi \ifx \hhline \@undefined \else \d
ef \HH@box ##1##2{\vbox {{\ifx \CT@drsc@ \relax \else \global \dimen \thr@@ \tw
@ \arrayrulewidth \global \advance \dimen \thr@@ \doublerulesep {\CT@drsc@ \hru
le \@height \dimen \thr@@ \vskip -\dimen \thr@@ }\fi \CT@arc@ \hrule \@height \
arrayrulewidth \@width ##1 \vskip \doublerulesep \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidt
h \@width ##2}}} \def \HH@loop {\ifx \@tempb `\def \next ####1{\the \toks@ \cr 
}\else \let \next \HH@let \ifx \@tempb |\if@tempswa \ifx \CT@drsc@ \relax \HH@a
dd {\hskip \doublerulesep }\else \HH@add {{\CT@drsc@ \vrule \@width \doublerule
sep }}\fi \fi \@tempswatrue \HH@add {{\CT@arc@ \vline }}\else \ifx \@tempb :\if
@tempswa \ifx \CT@drsc@ \relax \HH@add {\hskip \doublerulesep }\else \HH@add {{
\CT@drsc@ \vrule \@width \doublerulesep }}\fi \fi \@tempswatrue \HH@add {\@temp
c \HH@box \arrayrulewidth \arrayrulewidth \@tempc }\else \ifx \@tempb ####\if@t
empswa \HH@add {\hskip \doublerulesep }\fi \@tempswatrue \HH@add {{\CT@arc@ \vl
ine \copy \@ne \@tempc \vline }}\else \ifx \@tempb ~\@tempswafalse \if@firstamp
 \@firstampfalse \else \HH@add {&\omit }\fi \ifx \CT@drsc@ \relax \HH@add {\hfi
l }\else \HH@add {{\CT@drsc@ \leaders \hrule \@height \HH@height \hfil }}\fi \e
lse \ifx \@tempb -\@tempswafalse \gdef \HH@height {\arrayrulewidth }\if@firstam
p \@firstampfalse \else \HH@add {&\omit }\fi \HH@add {{\CT@arc@ \leaders \hrule
 \@height \arrayrulewidth \hfil }}\else \ifx \@tempb =\@tempswafalse \gdef \HH@
height {\dimen \thr@@ }\if@firstamp \@firstampfalse \else \HH@add {&\omit }\fi 
\HH@add {\rlap {\copy \@ne }\leaders \copy \@ne \hfil \llap {\copy \@ne }}\else
 \ifx \@tempb t\HH@add {\def \HH@height {\dimen \thr@@ }\HH@box \doublerulesep 
\z@ }\@tempswafalse \else \ifx \@tempb b\HH@add {\def \HH@height {\dimen \thr@@
 }\HH@box \z@ \doublerulesep }\@tempswafalse \else \ifx \@tempb >\def \next ###
#1####2{\HH@add {{\baselineskip \p@ \relax ####2\global \setbox \@ne \HH@box \d
oublerulesep \doublerulesep }}\HH@let !}\else \ifx \@tempb \@sptoken \let \next
 \HH@spacelet \else \PackageWarning {hhline}{\meaning \@tempb \space ignored in
 \noexpand \hhline argument\MessageBreak }\fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \
fi \fi \next } \lowercase {\def \HH@spacelet } {\futurelet \@tempb \HH@loop } \
fi  \ifx \longtable \@undefined \else \def \LT@@hline {\ifx \LT@next \hline \gl
obal \let \LT@next \@gobble \ifx \CT@drsc@ \relax \gdef \CT@LT@sep {\noalign {\
penalty -\@medpenalty \vskip \doublerulesep }}\else \gdef \CT@LT@sep {\multispa
n \LT@cols {\CT@drsc@ \leaders \hrule \@height \doublerulesep \hfill }\cr }\fi 
\else \global \let \LT@next \empty \gdef \CT@LT@sep {\noalign {\penalty -\@lowp
enalty \vskip -\arrayrulewidth }}\fi \ifnum 0=`{\fi }\multispan \LT@cols {\CT@a
rc@ \leaders \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \hfill }\cr \CT@LT@sep \multispan 
\LT@cols {\CT@arc@ \leaders \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \hfill }\cr \noalig
n {\penalty \@M }\LT@next } \fi 
>     fontspec-luatex -> \tl_set_eq:NN \cyrillicencoding \g_fontspec_encoding_t
l \tl_set_eq:NN \latinencoding \g_fontspec_encoding_tl \RenewDocumentCommand \o
ldstylenums {m}{\__fontspec_main_oldstylenums:n {##1}}\fontspec_maybe_setup_mat
hs: 
>     amsmath -> \reset@strutbox@ \MakeRobust \dddot \MakeRobust \ddddot \Umath
charnumdef \std@minus \Umathcodenum `\-\relax \Umathcharnumdef \std@equal \Umat
hcodenum `\=\relax \expandafter \let \csname overleftarrow \endcsname \@undefin
ed \expandafter \let \csname overrightarrow \endcsname \@undefined \MakeRobust 
\overrightarrow \MakeRobust \overleftarrow \MakeRobust \overleftrightarrow \Mak
eRobust \underrightarrow \MakeRobust \underleftarrow \MakeRobust \underleftrigh
tarrow 
>     unicode-math-luatex -> \__um_define_math_chars: \tl_if_eq:onT {\g__fontsp
ec_mathrm_tl }{\rmdefault }{\__fontspec_setmathrm_hook:nn {}{}}\tl_if_eq:onT {\
g__fontspec_mathsf_tl }{\sfdefault }{\__fontspec_setmathsf_hook:nn {}{}}\tl_if_
eq:onT {\g__fontspec_mathtt_tl }{\ttdefault }{\__fontspec_setmathtt_hook:nn {}{
}}\bool_if:NF \g__um_main_font_defined_bool \__um_load_lm: \__um_setup_mathtext
: \__um_define_prime_commands: \__um_define_prime_chars: \cs_new_protected:Npn 
\__um_patch_url: {\tl_put_left:Nn \Url@FormatString {\__um_switch_to:n {literal
}}\tl_put_right:Nn \UrlSpecials {\do \`{\mathchar `\`}\do \'{\mathchar `\'}\do 
\${\mathchar `\$}\do \&{\mathchar `\&}}}\@ifpackageloaded {url}{\__um_patch_url
: }{}\cs_new_protected:Npn \__um_patch_mathtools_B: {\cs_set_eq:NN \MToverbrack
et \overbracket \cs_set_eq:NN \MTunderbracket \underbracket \AtBeginDocument {\
msg_warning:nn {unicode-math}{mathtools-overbracket}\cs_set:Npn \downbracketfil
l ####1####2{\tl_set:Nn \l_MT_bracketheight_fdim {.27ex}\downbracketend {####1}
{####2}\leaders \vrule \@height ####1\@depth \z@ \hfill \downbracketend {####1}
{####2}}\cs_set:Npn \upbracketfill ####1####2{\tl_set:Nn \l_MT_bracketheight_fd
im {.27ex}\upbracketend {####1}{####2}\leaders \vrule \@height \z@ \@depth ####
1\hfill \upbracketend {####1}{####2}}\cs_set_eq:NN \Uoverbracket \overbracket \
cs_set_eq:NN \Uunderbracket \underbracket \cs_set_eq:NN \overbracket \MToverbra
cket \cs_set_eq:NN \underbracket \MTunderbracket }}\@ifpackageloaded {mathtools
}{\__um_patch_mathtools_B: }{}\cs_new_protected:Npn \__um_patch_mathtools_C: {\
msg_warning:nn {unicode-math}{mathtools-colon}\DeclareDocumentCommand \dblcolon
 {}{\Colon }\DeclareDocumentCommand \coloneqq {}{\coloneq }\DeclareDocumentComm
and \Coloneqq {}{\Coloneq }\DeclareDocumentCommand \eqqcolon {}{\eqcolon }}\@if
packageloaded {mathtools}{\__um_patch_mathtools_C: }{}\Umathcharnumdef \std@min
us \Umathcodenum `-\Umathcharnumdef \std@equal \Umathcodenum `=\debug_suspend: 
\__um_resolve_greek: \debug_resume: \@ifpackageloaded {amsmath}{}{\__um_redefin
e_radical: }\__um_setup_active_frac: \g__um_secret_hook_tl 
> Document-level (top-level) code (executed last):
>     ---
> Extra code for next invocation:
>     ---
> Rules:
>     ---
> Execution order:
>     color, colortbl, fontspec-luatex, amsmath, unicode-math-luatex.
<recently read> }
 
l.6 \ShowHook{begindocument}
                          
?
```

The exact code chunks left by each package may not make exciting reading but it does show that only these packages are of interest

```
> Execution order:
>     color, colortbl, fontspec-luatex, amsmath, unicode-math-luatex.
```

from there it would be easy to make an example and removing half of the packages at a time narrow down to find `unicode-math` is responsible here.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about ShowHook

Comment: Where are things like `\ShowHook` documented? I expect that there are many other related tools that I am not aware of.

Comment: @JeffreyGoldberg `texdoc lthooks-doc`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the answer is the [unicode-math](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math?lang=en) package. §6.2 of its documentation says

> unicode-math defines the macros by \AtBeginDocument, namely delays the definition until \begin{document} is met. If you want to overwrite a macro defined by unicode-math, please redefine it in \AtBeginDocument after loading this package.

It behaves this way because it very reasonably wants fonts to be set up before defining some macros.

I did not identify the package defining \Eta in any particularly systematic way, but I did use Google to search for \mitEta (which I take to be for "Math Italic Eta"). Several references to unicode-math showed up. So I don't really have a general answer to the general form of my question.

Comment: "reasonably" is debatable:-) https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/465

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I haven't looked at the source. I assumed that the reason it wants fonts loaded is to be able to see if, say, U+1D6E8 is available. Such a check wouldn't be fully reliable as in my case because I was using \Eta in contexts with non-main fonts.

But I am just speculating about rationale.

Comment: no it doesnt check indivdual characters. some things need to wait until the main font has been set to stix2 or cambria or whatever but the bulk setting of ~2000 or so `\foo`  commands to unicode slots could be done  earlier (or in the format)